# Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file

Tags: php

```
<?php

require_once('connect.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) & !empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    $fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]; $fileTmpLoc =
    $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]; $fileType =
    $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"];  $fileSize =
    $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"];  $fileErrorMsg =
    $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"]; $data = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");

    $nr= rand(1, 30); $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);  $fileExt =
    end($kaboom);    if (!$fileTmpLoc) { 
    echo "";
    exit();      
} else if($fileSize > 15242880) { 
    echo "Imagine > 15MB";
    unlink($fileTmpLoc); 
    exit();      
} else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {

    echo "Format permis gif/png/jpeg/jpg";
    unlink($fileTmpLoc); 
    exit();      
} else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) { 
    echo "Incercati din nou";
    exit(); 
}    
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "galerie/uploads/$nr$username.jpeg");

if ($moveResult != true) {
    echo "Fisierul NU a fost incarcat";
    unlink($fileTmpLoc); 
    exit(); } 

    include_once("ak_php_img_lib_1.0.php"); $target_file =
    "galerie/uploads/$nr$username.jpeg"; $resized_file =
    "galerie/uploads/r$nr$username.jpeg"; $edit_target =
    "$nr$username.jpeg"; 
    $wmax = 300; 
    $hmax = 300;

    ak_img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);
    $_SESSION['editname'] = $edit_target; 
    header("Refresh:0");    
    exit();     
 } else {       
    session_destroy();          
    require "../login.php"; 
} 
?>
```

Until upload a file, I recived this errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in
>   E:\LICENTA\xampp\htdocs\licentaCC\galerie\image_upload_script.php on
>   line 42
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in
>   E:\LICENTA\xampp\htdocs\licentaCC\galerie\image_upload_script.php on
>   line 43
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in
>   E:\LICENTA\xampp\htdocs\licentaCC\galerie\image_upload_script.php on
>   line 44
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in
>   E:\LICENTA\xampp\htdocs\licentaCC\galerie\image_upload_script.php on
>   line 45
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in
>   E:\LICENTA\xampp\htdocs\licentaCC\galerie\image_upload_script.php on
>   line 46

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Paste your HTML code here.

Comment: Please do a Google search or a SO search before asking a question that has been ask a 1000 times before

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I already do that, but i can't solve the error

Comment: `uploaded_file` has to be the name of your HTML `<input type="file" name="uploaded_file">`

Comment: Yes. But if no file are uplaoded, i recive that notice. 
Whem I select the file, notice dissappear

Comment: I need to put in this code "if(isset($_POST['uploadedfile)